# How to create alternating non-overlapping dashes in contour line

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to mark one particular contour of a function with alternating and non-overlapping red and green dashes. My first idea was to use the parametrized dash minilanguage, but that gives an error:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# prepare the data
delta = 0.025
x = np.arange(-1.0, 1.0, delta)
y = np.arange(-1.0, 1.0, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = np.exp(-(X ** 2) - Y ** 2)
Z2 = np.exp(-((X - 1) ** 2) - (Y - 1) ** 2)
Z = (Z1 - Z2) * 2

# the actual plotting
plt.contour(X, Y, Z, levels=[1.1], linestyles=(0, (5, 5)), colors="red", alpha=0.5)
plt.contour(X, Y, Z, levels=[1.1], linestyles=(5, (5, 5)), colors="green", alpha=0.5)

plt.show()
```

```
ValueError: Do not know how to convert [0] to dashes
```

Any hints?

Comment: Maybe [Contourplot in matplot showing incorrect linestyle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62141330/7758804)

Comment: `linestyles=[(0, (5, 5))]` seems to work as desired. See also [Can the "off" color be set for a Matplotlib dashed line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59131436/12046409)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[]` brackets were missing:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# prepare the data
delta = 0.025
x = np.arange(-1.0, 1.0, delta)
y = np.arange(-1.0, 1.0, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = np.exp(-(X ** 2) - Y ** 2)
Z2 = np.exp(-((X - 1) ** 2) - (Y - 1) ** 2)
Z = (Z1 - Z2) * 2

# the actual plotting
plt.contour(X, Y, Z, levels=[1.1], linestyles=[(0, (5, 5))], colors="red")
plt.contour(X, Y, Z, levels=[1.1], linestyles=[(5, (5, 5))], colors="green")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Thanks to @JohanC for the reply!